# I can't set an MVC checkbox as checked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC, I'm using helpers to create a checkbox like so

```
@Html.CheckBox("MDCCheckbox", true, new { @class = "LineCheckbox" })
@Html.Label("MDCCheckbox", "MDC") &nbsp;
```

Nothing fancy.

I want to be able to (un)check the box in jquery.

I can uncheck it very easily, but I can't set it to checked.
It's something with the way MVC renders the html, but I can't figure it out.

I know that I can just create the elements myself, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

This is how that razor is rendered into html (with a matching input element to pass true/false to the server).

```
<input checked="checked" class="LineCheckbox" id="MDCCheckbox" name="MDCCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="MDCCheckbox" type="hidden" value="false" />
<label for="MDCCheckbox">MDC</label>
```

I've created a fiddle to make it easier to play with and test.  I can't even get it to work in the fiddle.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZsMd/)

Here is the jquery

```
$(".check").click(function () {        
    $(".LineCheckbox").attr("checked", true);
});
$(".uncheck").click(function () {        
    $(".LineCheckbox").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `.prop()` to set property checked instead:

```
$(".check").click(function () {        
    $(".LineCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
});
$(".uncheck").click(function () {        
    $(".LineCheckbox").prop("checked", false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(".check").click(function () {        
    $(".LineCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
});
$(".uncheck").click(function () {        
    $(".LineCheckbox").prop("checked", false);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DhbYx/1/)

A good read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(".check").click(function () {        
    $(".LineCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
});
```

You can see the [difference between `.prop()` and `.attr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

[<kbd>**Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZsMd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
$(".check").click(function () {        
    $('.LineCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
});
$(".uncheck").click(function () {        
     $('.LineCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```